# React Native Redefinition of 'RCTMethodInfo' in RCTBridgeModule.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

React Native 0.49 in iOS I clone my project install npm and link from git and run but it has error in `RCTBridgeModule.h` in code

```
typedef struct RCTMethodInfo {
  const char *const jsName;
  const char *const objcName;
  const BOOL isSync;
} RCTMethodInfo;
```

it have 2 Error

> Redefinition of 'RCTMethodInfo' and Typedef redefinition with different types ('struct (anonymous struct at ../../react-native/React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:57:16)' vs 'struct RCTMethodInfo')

I fine solution and included

```
 #if __has_include(<React/RCTBridgeModule.h>)
 #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
 else
 #import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
 #endif
```

but it error same

Comment: where did u added. i am getting same error?

Comment: in head after `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> #import <React/RCTDefines.h>`

Comment: Please post complete solution.

Comment: `react-native upgrade` works for me ..

Answer (score 3):

I happend to encountered this issue just now.It was caused by a third party
penguin called "**react-native-weibo"**.I just changed #import "RCTBridgeModule" to #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h> inside RCTWeiboAPI
,then everything is ok now.

so if your issue is caused by third party penguin also,just try to change  #import "xxxx.h" to #import <React/xxxx.h> inside third party API.

Hope it works.

Comment: `caused by a third party penguin`
would be too much fun to work on RN if this was true :D

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue and solved it by deleting Derived Data. The issue was appear cause of up-gradation of project via xcode 10. Previous project's derived data from xcode 9 also present which was unable to delete by cleaning the project for some reason.

You can manually delete the project build files in Derived Data or use command below.

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Hope it helps!